# Backtracking N stairs question getting 0 cases Java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, backtracking, pass-by-value

N Stairs question is to compute the number of distinct ways to reach the top. Each time you can either climb 1 or 2 steps. For example, if the input is 3, the desired output is 3 (1+1+1,1+2,2+1).

I am learning backtracking in Java, so I want to implement it in this question, although DP would work better in such a case. I view it as a practice if I understand backtracking well, but apparently not. I got stuck because my algorithm gives me a `0` output for every case. Below is my code:

```
    public int climbStairs(int n) {
        int cnt=0,k=0;
        climb(cnt,k,n);
        return cnt;
    }
    public void climb(int cnt, int k, int n){
        if(k==n){
            cnt++;
            return; 
        }
        for(int i=1;i<3;++i){
            if(k<n){
                k+=i;
                climb(cnt,k,n);
                k-=i;
            }
        }
    }
```

Could you help me figure out what's wrong with my code? I tried debugging it, and I noticed every time it returns, `cnt` will automatically change to `0`, but I just can't figure out why.

Thank you so much in advance!

Edited version:

```
public class ClimbStairs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(climbStairs(3));
    }
    public static int climbStairs(int n) {
        int cnt=0,k=0;
        return climb(cnt, k, n);
    }
    public static int climb(int cnt, int k, int n){
        if(k==n){
            cnt++;
        }
        for(int i=1;i<3;++i){
            if(k<n){
                k+=i;
                climb(cnt,k,n);
                k-=i;
            }
        }
        return cnt;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Thank you for your suggestion! I have added some descriptions. That would be great if you could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every recursive implementation consists of **two parts**:

- **base case** - a situation (or situations) that represent the edge-case for which the result is already known. For this problem, if we choose to track the number of *steps* (going forward I'd say that it's not mandatory) then the **base case** is when the number of *stairs* is equal to the number of *steps*, i.e. `k == n`. And if we don't track the number of *steps* then the **base case** will be represented with *two edge-cases*: there are *no stairs* at all - no *steps* required and there's only one way to take zero steps, so the output is `1`, and the second is when we have only *one stair* then we have to take one *step* and the output is also `1`.
- **recursive case** - is the part where recursive calls a made and where main logic resides.

We have two possible branches in the **recursive case** for every `k < n`: we can either take **1 step** or **2 steps**. And therefore we have to make *two recursive calls* that represent these situations. All these calls can be represented graphically as a tree. To understand the logic better can you drow this *tree of method-calls* starting from the first one that is made inside the `climbStairs()` and track the value of `k` for each call. Until the condition `k < n` is meat each *vertex* will spawn two branches. When `k` is greater or equal to `n` the call hits the **base case**. And starting from the bottom to the top you can figure out what are the return values for each call.

Also, note that instead of being `void` your method must return the number of paths that are found. And the third parameter that represents this number is redundant.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(climbStairs(1));
    System.out.println(climbStairs(3));
}

public static int climbStairs(int n) {
    if (n < 0) { // cut off the incorrect input
        return 0;
    }
    return climb(n, 0);
}

public static int climb(int n, int k){
    if (k > n) { // an invalid situation
        return 0;
    }
    if (k == n) { // a path was found
        return 1;
    }
    // there are two alternative branches for every k < n
    int count = 0;
    count += climb(n, k + 1); // move one step forward
    count += climb(n, k + 2); // move two steps forward
    return count;
}
```

As I said above tracking the number of *steps* isn't required. Instead, we can *reduce the number of stairs* while making recursive calls. And that will allow us to place all logic in a **single method**. Like that:

```
public static int climbStairs(int n) {
    if (n < 0) { // cut off the incorrect input
        return 0;
    }
    if (n == 0) { // a base case when we have NO stairs - we have to take zero steps (there's only ONE way to do that)
        return 1;
    }
    if (n == 1) { // a base case when we have only one stair - we have to take one step (there's only ONE way to do that)
        return 1;
    }
    // there are two alternative branches for every n > 1
    int count = 0;
    count += climbStairs(n - 1); // move one step forward
    count += climbStairs(n - 2); // move two steps forward
    return count;
}
```

**Output**

```
1
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is pass-by-value. That means your that your `cnt` variable in your `climbStairs` method is not shared; it is unique to you. When you invoke `climb`, you pass the value it holds (`0` every time here), and `climb` has its own variable (also called `cnt`). It modifies its own `cnt` value which is tossed in the garbage when that method ends (all parameters and all local variables are always tossed in the garbage when a method ends).

You want to *return* `cnt`:

```
// In climbStairs:
return climb(cnt, k, n);

// In climb, at the end:
return cnt;
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the problem for me! I am sometimes confused with pass-by-value. I tried to modify my code according to your suggestion, but it still gives me `0`. Could you help me check again if I made some silly mistakes? My edited version can be found in my original question.

Comment: You to use the result of `climb(cnt,k,n);`.

Answer (score 0):

We are given that there are `N` steps. Let `n` equal the number of two-steps taken (`0 <= n <= N/2`). If `n` two-steps are taken `N-2*n` one-steps are taken.

Let `f(n)` equal the number of combinations of one-steps and two-steps when there are `n` two-steps. This is merely a coefficient in a [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution#:%7E:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20the%20multinomial,sided%20die%20rolled%20n%20times.) having two distinct items:

```
m = N-2*n
f(n) = (n+m)!/(n!*m!)
```

To obtain the desired total number of combinations we simply sum `f(n)` over `n = 0..N/2`.

---

For `N = 3` (the example given in the question), the number of combinations is computed as follows.

```
n = 0
m = N-2*n = 3
f(n) = (n+m)!/(n!*m!) = 3!/(0!*3!) = 1    # 111
```

```
n = 1
m = N-2*n = 1
f(n) = (n+m)!/(n!*m!) = 2!/(1!*1!) = 2    # 12 and 21
```

```
f(0) + f(1) = 3
```

---

For `N = 5`, the number of combinations is computed as follows.

```
n = 0
m = N-2*n = 5
f(n) = (n+m)!/(n!*m!) = 5!/(0!*5!) = 1    # 11111
```

```
n = 1
m = N-2*n = 3
f(n) = (n+m)!/(n!*m!) = 4!/(1!*3!) = 4    # 2111 1211 1121 1112
```

```
n = 2
m = N-2*n = 1
f(n) = (n+m)!/(n!*m!) = 3!/(2!*1!) = 3    # 212 221 122
```

```
f(0) + f(1) + f(2) = 8
```