# Problem understanding intuitively the climb stairs problem's solution, why isn't t(n-1) + t(n-2) not t(n) = t(n-1) + t(n-2) + 2?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

Here is the problem:

You have n-steps to climb. You can only climb 1 or 2 steps at a time. find the number of ways to reach Nth step.

the solution is described as t(n) = t(n-1) + t(n-2).

I keep thinking why not add a constant 2, to represent the final one or two step from t(n-1) and t(n-2)? I having trouble intuitively, why it's not added at each stage?

the problem is the sum of t(n-1) and t(n-2) but I feel like where does it account for taking the one or two step backwards?

since there are two option and you have yet to take the two steps at t(n-1) or t(n-2) shouldn't there be a constant added at each step? How can I conceptualize this?

Comment: You don't have to account the steps you take. You just have to find the number of ways in which this can be done. Constant 2 you are referring is the steps

Comment: The same stair-climbing problem was addressed recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71246708/backtracking-n-stairs-question-getting-0-cases-java), though the question asked was not the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> and you have yet to take the two steps

But you're not counting *steps* though, you're counting *ways*. Your final step/jump can be a one or a two. So you add the number of ways that led you to n-1 with the number of ways that led you to n-2. That's your answer.

Comment: Yep, counting the steps is not that difficult, is it... ?

Answer (score 1):

If you play the video backward, from the step `n` you move either to step `n-1` or to step `n-2`.

Hence, the number of ways to reach the step `n` equals the number of ways to reach  the step `n-1` plus the number of ways to reach to step `n-2`, as these are distinct ways to reach `n`. There is no reason to add anything.

---

If you are still not convinced, let us try a few cases.

With n=1, there is a single way (1).

With n=2, there are 2 ways (1+1, 2)

With n=3, there are 3 ways (1+1+1, 2+1, 1+2)

With n=4, there are 5 ways (1+1+1+1, 1+2+1, 2+1+1, 1+1+2, 2+2)

With n=5, there are 8 ways (1+1+1+1+1, 1+1+2+1, 1+2+1+1, 2+1+1+1, 1+1+1+2, 1+2+2, 2+1+2, 2+2+1)

You should recognize the Fibonacci numbers.